# Detecting piano note using C# with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, goertzel-algorithm

I am trying to write a program that identifies the note I play on a piano,I found out that the Goertzel filter is a easy to implement algorithm but I don't know how to use it.

Here is the code:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Windows;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfTest {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        private BufferedWaveProvider buffer;
        private WaveIn waveIn;
        private WaveOut waveOut;
        private const double TargetFreaquency = 261.626;//C4 note
        private const int SampleRate = 44100;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeSound();
            waveIn.StartRecording();
            waveOut.Play();
        }

        private void InitializeSound() {
            waveIn = new WaveIn();
            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
            waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveInDataAvailable;
            waveOut.Init(buffer);
        }

        private void WaveInDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e) {
            buffer.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

            var floatBuffer = new List<float>();
            for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2) {
                short sample = (short)((e.Buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
                                        e.Buffer[index + 0]);
                float sample32 = sample / 32768f;
                floatBuffer.Add(sample32);
            }

            if (NotePlayed(floatBuffer.ToArray(), e.BytesRecorded)) {
                Console.WriteLine("You have played C4");
            }
        }

        private bool NotePlayed(float[] buffer, int end) {
            double power = GoertzelFilter(buffer, TargetFreaquency, buffer.Length);
            if (power > 500) return true;
            return false;
        }

        private double GoertzelFilter(float[] samples, double targetFreaquency, int end) {
            double sPrev = 0.0;
            double sPrev2 = 0.0;
            int i;
            double normalizedfreq = targetFreaquency / SampleRate;
            double coeff = 2 * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * normalizedfreq);
            for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                double s = samples[i] + coeff * sPrev - sPrev2;
                sPrev2 = sPrev;
                sPrev = s;
            }
            double power = sPrev2 * sPrev2 + sPrev * sPrev - coeff * sPrev * sPrev2;
            return power;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not working correctly but how should I do to write in the console:"You have played C4" every time I play the C4 note to the microphone?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I think your question is a little unclear on what you actually need help with. You'r code says _"You have played C4"_, so do you need help with these methods because something is wrong with them, or do you need help with how to call these methods?

Comment: Hello and thank you! i needed help with the methods because there was an error somewhere and I couldn't figure out where.I already got the answer to this question, but i will try to be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that the microphone input will be 16-bit PCM samples at 44100Hz.  That's not necessarily the case.  You can check the 'default' microphone format, as well as force it to what you're expecting, as follows:

```
private void InitializeSound()
{
    waveIn = new WaveIn();

    // Add this here to see what the waveIn default format is.
    // Step through this line in the debugger.  If this isn't
    // 44100Hz sampling rate, 16-bit PCM, 1-channel, then that's
    // probably what's going wrong.
    WaveFormat checkformat = waveIn.WaveFormat;

    // Note that these are the default values if we used the 
    // parameterless WaveFormat constructor, but just expanding
    // here to show that we're forcing the input to what you're 
    // expecting:
    WaveFormat myformat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
    waveIn.WaveFormat = myformat;
    SampleRate = myformat.SampleRate;

    waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveInDataAvailable;

    waveOut = new WaveOut();
    buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
    waveOut.Init(buffer);
}
```

I'm not sure on the endianness when you're converting the `short` to `float` in your event handler (I'm old, and I can't remember which end is which anymore :)), so that might also be an issue.  You would probably be better off using `BitConverter.ToInt16` to do that, rather than the shift/add that you're doing now:

```
private void WaveInDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    buffer.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

    var floatBuffer = new List<float>();
    for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
    {
        short sample = BitConvert.ToInt16(e.Buffer, index);
        float sample32 = (float)sample;
        sample32 /= (float)Int16.MaxValue;
        floatBuffer.Add(sample32);
    }

    if (NotePlayed(floatBuffer.ToArray(), e.BytesRecorded))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have played C4");
    }
}
```

It also looks like the `end` parameter to `NotePlayed` is unused, which is actually good!  Inferring the meaning of an `end` parameter, `e.BytesRecorded` wouldn't be the correct value anyway since that's not the sample count.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did as you said and now it works, the problem was that the default sample rate was 8000 Hz and not 44100 Hz.
Now every time I play a C4 note I get several "You have played C4" lines written in the console but I think that is normal since the note I play does resonate for a while.
Again, thank you for your fast and complete answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Yeah, you'll see the string several times, I suspect once for each `DataAvailable` event that is generated before the note dissipates.